# ExpandableListView expanding adds extra space beneath list on large screens

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-alertdialog

My ExpandableListView behaves normally on my Galaxy Note 3 as pictured below:

[image: Note 3]

But on my Nexus 7 and Galaxy Note 10.1, there's a bunch of extra space that appears when I expand the list to show a child. (The space does not appear until I click a parent.)

From Nexus 7:

[image: nexus 7]

My first guess is that there is something inconsistent with my layout resources (I had different layout resources for sw-600 and sw-700) but removing the larger screen resources, the behaviour is the same. I also commented out everything in the getGroupView and getChildView methods in my adapter class other than inflating the layouts, and still this behaviour. So now I have no idea what is causing this behaviour. I guess the other significant detail is that I'm doing this in an AlertDialog, but it doesn't explain why it only seems to happen on larger devices.

Initializing the ExpandableListAdapter and AlertDialog:

```
private void showServicesDialog(final ArrayList<Service> services) {
        View dView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_view, null);
        View header = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.service_list_header, null);
        AlertDialog servicesDialog = DialogHelper.createLayoutAlertDialog(activity, null, dView, 
                R.string.cancel, R.string.add_services, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (selectedServices.size() > 0) {
                    addServicesToBackend();
                } 
            }
        });

        ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) dView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        ServicesExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ServicesExpandableListAdapter(activity, services);
        list.setGroupIndicator(null);
        list.setSelector(R.drawable.list_selector_bg);
        list.setDivider(null);
        list.addHeaderView(header);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        servicesDialog.show();
}
```

From my Adapter class:

```
  public ServicesExpandableListAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<Service> s) {
        activity = (MyActivity) act;
        services = s;

        itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for (int i = 0; i < services.size(); i++)
            itemChecked.add(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return services.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return services.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return services.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    private static class ParentViewHolder {
        TextView nameTV, categoryTV, expandTV, typeTV, amountTV, warningTV;
        CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ParentViewHolder holder = null;
        final Service service = services.get(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.service_list_parent_item, null);
            holder = new ParentViewHolder();
            holder.nameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            holder.typeTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeTV);
            holder.categoryTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.categoryTV);
            holder.expandTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandTV);
            holder.amountTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountTV);   
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectCB);   
            holder.warningTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.warningTV); 

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ParentViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //content commented out

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ChildViewHolder {
        TextView typeTV, priceTV, infoTV;
        CheckBox weekdaysCB, saturdaysCB, sundaysCB, holidaysCB;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.service_list_child_item, null);
            holder = new ChildViewHolder();
            holder.typeTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.typeTV);
            holder.priceTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceTV);
            holder.infoTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.infoTV);
            holder.weekdaysCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.weekdaysCB);
            holder.saturdaysCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saturdaysCB);
            holder.sundaysCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sundaysCB);
            holder.holidaysCB = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holidaysCB);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //content commented out

        return convertView;
    }
```

service_list_parent_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <View
            android:id="@+id/topDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/gray_divider" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/warningTV"
            android:text="Service name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/regularText" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameTV"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/holo_light_purple"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clock_tiny_white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryTV"
            style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/typeTV"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/expandTV"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/typeTV"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Category Name that is super long" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/warningTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/selectCB"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/action_bar_selector"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_warning_gray"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/selectCB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amountTV"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button_selector"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/expandTV"
             style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bottomDivider"
             android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_expand_arrow_gray"
             android:gravity="bottom"
             android:paddingBottom="5dp"
             android:text="@string/expand"
             android:textColor="@color/lighter_gray_text" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomDivider"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:background="@color/blue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

service_list_child_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_tasklist" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/topDivider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/blue" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/centerView"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topDivider"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/typeTV"
        style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topDivider"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerView"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_clock_tiny_purple"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/time_service"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_light_purple" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priceTV"
        style="@style/regularTextSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/typeTV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerView"
        android:text="35e/hr"
        android:textColor="@color/blue" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/typeTV"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/weekdaysCB"
            style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/weekdays" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/holidaysCB"
            style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/weekdaysCB"
            android:layout_below="@+id/weekdaysCB"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/holidays" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/saturdaysCB"
            style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/weekdaysCB"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/weekdaysCB"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/saturdays" />
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sundaysCB"
            style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/holidaysCB"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/saturdaysCB"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/sundays" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/infoTV"
        style="@style/regularTextVerySmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And lastly, expandable_list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_tasklist"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        style="@style/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/gray_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:childDivider="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u mark it with red marker for the extra space .Bcoz i can't find any

Comment: Sorry! Edited my post.

Comment: create the child view differently for the 7inch device and the 10 inch device.

Comment: any updates if u solved this?